# SOAP and PayPal - passing custom variables

Tags: soap, paypal

I am working on a project where the client is using SOAP to pass their data to PayPal on checkout.

The thing I am having trouble with is: passing a coupon/discount code - to the PayPal backend using SOAP.

I need to find a way using this SOAP implementation to pass the **actual coupon code to PayPal for the client knows which code was used.** I tried the hidden input "custom" but doesnt seem to be sent over to PayPal.

**I see the returned markup (SOAP) in the firebug console tab. I just need to pass the coupon code name to PayPal.**

Comment: Does the PayPal API accept a coupon code? Does it have a place for user-defined data?

Comment: It does; "custom". However, Coughlin, you refer to "the hidden input", which makes me wonder what product you're using. PayPal Website Payments Standard is controlled through HTML mainly. Or are you using BMCreateButton? If not, are you using Express Checkout (SetExpressCheckout)?